# Delay bindings in model with ObjectProxy

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, binding

My application currently has 2 classes:

- `MyModel` - Contains all the *raw* data required by the view
- `MyView`  - A component to be loaded and display the model's data

`MyModel` currently binds directly to `MyView`, so when a change occurs in the model it is changed immediately in the view.

What I would like to do is delay *some* of the bindings until after a specific action occurs in the view. For example some bindings won't update while a video or sound is playing in the view.

My plan for this is to create an additional class:

- `MyViewModel` - Abstracts `MyModel` and contains the view specific data *as it is required* by the view. `MyView` can bind directly to this class (instead of binding to `MyModel`) and the data will always be correct.

**What's the best way to go about abstracting `MyModel`?** I have been looking at extending **[`ObjectProxy`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html)** for this, but I'm not sure if it's possible to delay a binding.

Comment: Using ObjectProxy (or any kind of proxy class for that matter) to organize the raw data model into a presentation model seems like a good approach to me. However I wonder why you'd want to delay the binding execution. It sounds like you should rather use States to present the view in one way or the other according to some conditions. Of course I can't know for sure without a more concrete example.

Comment: @RIAstar: I decided to use `Proxy` instead of `ObjectProxy` in the end. The reason is that while the view is playing a video the bindings should be frozen, but I think states could be messy because it will depend which options the user has checked for which variables will be frozen. I created a new class `BindableObjectCache` for this, maybe I will post after some testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change/remove/add bindings at runtime, try 
BindingUtils and ChangeWatcher.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `ChangeWatcher`s already, but I was wondering if there was some way to freeze bindings. In particular best practices for creating a presentation model that would cache bindings from a model.